# Set image in cardview one by one from drawable

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-drawable, android-cardview

I am trying to add images in a cardview from drawable and text one by one using a recyclerview. say there are 10 images in my drawable i want to use only 5 of them. So how to do that ?
here is my cardview :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/placeCard"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/card_corner_radius">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/placeImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <!-- Used for the ripple effect on touch -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainHolder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/placeNameHolder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/placeName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

here is my recyclerview adapter :

```
public class SubPlaceAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SubPlaceRecyclerViewHolder>{

String ImageUri;

@Override
public SubPlaceRecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_places, null);

    SubPlaceRecyclerViewHolder viewHolder = new SubPlaceRecyclerViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(SubPlaceRecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {

  //  holder.subPlaceImage
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 0;
}
```

}

my view holder :

```
public class SubPlaceRecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

protected ImageView subPlaceImage;
protected TextView subPlaceTitle;

public SubPlaceRecyclerViewHolder(View view) {
    super(view);
    this.subPlaceImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.placeImage);
    this.subPlaceTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.placeName);
}
```

}
thanks for the help :)

Comment: you know which 5 images you want to add?

Comment: @Dentor 
yea i know the names.

Comment: Did your problem solved with this answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Step 1.** First create a Model

```
public class ImageModel {
    int imageId;
    String aboutText;


    public int getImageId() {
        return imageId;
    }

    public void setImageId(int imageId) {
        this.imageId = imageId;
    }

    public String getAboutText() {
        return aboutText;
    }

    public void setAboutText(String aboutText) {
        this.aboutText = aboutText;
    }    
}
```

**Step 2.** Create a method which return arraylist of imageModel in your fragment/activity from where you set the adapter

```
private ArrayList<ImageModel> setImageData(){
        ArrayList<ImageModel> projectList=new ArrayList<>();

        ImageModel imageModel=new ImageModel();
        imageModel.setImageId(R.mipmap.ic_star_fill);
        imageModel.setAboutText("RandomText");
        projectList.add(imageModel);

        ImageModel imageModel1=new ProjectModel();
        projectModel.setImageId(R.mipmap.ic_star_fill);
        projectModel.setAboutText("RandomText");
        projectList.add(projectModel);
        return projectList;
    }
```

**Step 3.** Create constructor in your adapter which takes ArrayList as an argument

```
public SubPlaceAdapter(ArrayList<ImageModel> mImageList) {
        this.mActivity = mActivity;
        this.mImageList = mImageList);
    }
```

**Step 4.** Set your adapter in your fragment/ activity.

```
mSubPlaceAdapter = new SubPlaceAdapter(setImageData());
```

**Step 5.** Set your item in on BindView Holder

```
@Override 
public void onBindViewHolder(SubPlaceRecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {
 ImageModel imageModel= mImageList.get(position)
 holder.subPlaceImage.setImageResource(imageModel.getImageId());
} 

@Override 
public int getItemCount() { 
    return mImageList.size(); 
}
```

This code will give you the idea how to do it.Fill free to modify this answer.

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what i was looking for. Thanks for you efforts.